# RESTful way to check if I can POST a resource?

Tags: rest

I have a set of resources represented by the `/ticket/` endpoint. Users can `POST` a request to this endpoint in order to book a ticket, but this may fail due to various unpredictable situations (e.g. tickets have sold out).

I would like to be able to check before they start the booking process whether they will be able to complete the booking. For example, I make some `status` request and the server replies with "*Nope, those are already sold out*" and I don't bother filling in the booking form.

I feel like ideally this would be represented by some method on the same `/ticket/` endpoint, but I don't know which one would be most appropriate. I guess I could create a new endpoint `/ticket/availability` or something but that doesn't feel as tidy.

I found this discussion, but it's about `GET` rather than `POST`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10259779/1590962

Comment: Could you not start with a GET to check availability followed by a POST for booking?

Comment: That would require creating a new endpoint (e.g. `/ticket/availability`) since GET `/ticket/` has a different purpose (namely getting a list of all tickets). It might be that that's the best solution, but it doesn't feel so tidy and I was wondering if there was some more appropriate verb to use on the `/ticket/` endpoint.

Comment: This could have more to do with the user interface than REST. Depending on your use case, perhaps you could perform some 'type-ahead'-like GET requests when the user fills out the form and indicate that tickets are available - and then change the status if necessary.

Comment: Again, that requires creation of a new endpoint to receive those GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do. First, I'd make a POST to a `/reservation` which in the backend will put my tickets into a "reserved" state. Then, I'd make a second POST to the `/booking` resource in order to complete the transaction.

If the first POST to `reservation` fails (tickets are sold out), then the second POST (the booking process, filling forms, etc.) would be cancelled.

Feel free to change the URL resource names as you see fit.

The problem with your suggestion (to check the availability first) is that it could respond with an "OK, tickets available", you start filling forms, another user starts the same process and finishes the booking process faster than you and takes the tickets. By the time you finish filling your forms, the tickets have been given to someone else.

In my case, if another user tries to make a reservation, it would fail because it would check only tickets that are not in a "reserved" state.

Comment: In the case where we have a race condition between users, I'm perfectly happy to allocate first-come-first-served, and simply respond with an error to the second user. What I'm really trying to do is save the user having to fill in forms unnecessarily, if I can already tell him beforehand that there are no tickets left. I'm not sure making a preliminary POST to `/reservation` helps, since I don't yet know any info from the booking form (e.g. what kind of ticket the user wants to book).

Comment: You split the booking form into two. First form asks about the kind of ticket the user wants. If no tickets are available, the application will not ask for the second form info. But if they are available, continue to the second step and ask for the rest of the form info.